# Float right without changing vertical position

Tags: html, css

I have a heading on my web page that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to move those links all the way to the right, but when I do that, they also go up, like this:

[image]

Using a photo editing program, below is what I want (links on the bottom right). Well, ideally I'd like the whole thing centered vertically, but that seems to be asking too much of my abilities at the moment. I'd settle for the links staying on the bottom right.

[image]

The HTML is below. The only change is the div that has `float:right` in it (the div that contains the links). Doing that causes the links to move to the right, but then the also go up. I don't want the up. I've tried various things, but none are working. I must be missing something simple. How can I get the links to float right without going up?

```
        <div style="width:900px">
            <div class="center" id="headerTopics" style="white-space:nowrap">
                <img src="~/Content/images/wizard1.ico" height="48" width="48"/>
                <h1 style="font-size: 32px; display:inline">Presto</h1>
                <div style="display:inline; float:right;">
                    <a href="#" id="appsLink">Apps</a>
                    <a href="#" id="serversLink">Servers</a>
                    <a href="#" id="variablesLink">Variables</a>
                    <a href="#">Resolve</a>
                    <a href="#" id="installsLink">Installs</a>
                    <a href="#">Log</a>
                    <a href="#">Ping</a>
                    <a href="#">Global</a>
                    <a href="#">Security</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a margin to the floated div:

```
<div style="display:inline; float:right; margin-top:30px">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LMWEj/)**

Comment: By the way, how did you know to pick 30px? Is this a scenario where we just pick different margins until it looks good? So it's not a true alignment to the bottom, right?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add some margin to the top of the links to suit your preference, doing it with some css would look like this:

```
a {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Of course, that would apply to all 'a' tags in your document, so better would be to drill down a little. Perhaps put a class on the links div:

```
<div class="header-links" style="display:inline; float:right;">
```

and then the css would look like this:

```
.header-links a {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Remember that css goes in the header between style tags

```
<head>
    <style>
        .header-links a {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: I don't think anybody needs a basic-selector lesson. Obviously don't target all <a>s, if... you don't want to target all <a>s.

Comment: Actually, I thought that extra information was nice. I do very little web development, so I appreciated the help. (+1)

Comment: The asker wasn't using any css, so I wanted to make sure he understood the process. I know most won't need it.